# Using Hashmap ArrayList data generated in class to be used in MainActivity's ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm using a class to add all my json data into the bookList hashmap arraylist. Now I need my list on my MainActivity to update based on the data pulled in.

It seems based on my selection, it's logging to the logcat all the proper data pulled in, but nothing is showing up in the Listview, or resultsview for that matter...I'm assuming I have to return that bookList hashmap arraylist back to MainActivity to be used somehow...

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bookList;
    Context context;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_form);

        context = this;

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.game_list);

 // Possibly this is reading the wrong bookList, so it's not showing the ListView???
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context,
                bookList, R.layout.list_view, new String[] {
                        TAG_TITLE, TAG_INFO }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title, R.id.info });

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view, int position, long id) {

                resultsView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

                resultsView.setText("Book: "
                        + bookList.get(+position).get(TAG_TITLE)
                        + "\n"
                        + "About Book: "
                        + bookList.get(+position).get(TAG_INFO));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Json.java

```
public class Json {

        String TAG_PARENT = "results";
        String TAG_TITLE = "title";
        String TAG_INFO = "info";

    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bookList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            public static void pSearch(String item) {
                String origURL = item;
                URL resultURL;
                try {

                    resultURL = new URL(origURL);

                    Json json = new Json();
                    Json.SnagData gd = json.new SnagData();


                    gd.execute(resultURL);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                    Log.e("INCORRECT URL", "CHECK URL PASSED");

                    resultURL = null;
                }
            }
        public class SnagData extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {




                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                    bookList.clear();

                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

                    String fURL = "";
                    for (URL url : urls) {


                        fURL = NetworkConnection.getURLResponse(url);
                    }

                    return fURL;
                }


                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    try {


                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                        JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PARENT);

                        int j = results.length();


                        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {


                            JSONObject jo = results.getJSONObject(i);


                            String title = jo.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                            String info = jo.getString(TAG_INFO);


                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                            map.put(TAG_INFO, info);


                            bookList.add(map);


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: where is bookList populated with data.

Comment: in the onPostExecute of Json class in the forloop

Comment: Not sure what you meant by 'in asynctask' and 'use a interface' where do those portions of code go? Sorry I'm kind of new. Also I noticed your code wasn't using the R.id.game_list defined in my UI..so I'm not sure how that code will display the list properly

Comment: all those code in asynctask except the first which calls execute on asynctask the one below the section In Activity in my pst

Comment: do you mean in within "public class SnagData extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {" ? If so I tried that and I got the error 'The member interface returnListListener can only be defined in a top levle class' or interface

Comment: your can have the interface in a seperate .java file also. also post the updated code rather than commenting. Also is asynctask an inner class of activity?

Comment: Remove Json class. use Asynctask only. Why is Json class needed

Comment: AsyncTask is being used only on that SnagData class within the Json class... to make it a background operation. So I'm not sure what it is you're asking. Where would the 'new Json(MainActivity.this).execute(params); go - I really am confused on what that line is about.

Comment: pls check the edit now. no need for Json class and do get to know java interface more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a interface as a callback

Edit:

```
public class SnagData extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
  String TAG_PARENT = "results";
    String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    String TAG_INFO = "info";
    public interface returnListListener
    {
        public void returnList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list);
    }
    returnListListener mCallback;
public SnagData(Context context)
{
    mCallback = (returnListListener)context;
}

ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> booklist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        String fURL = "";
        for (URL url : urls) {


            fURL = NetworkConnection.getURLResponse(url);
        }

        return fURL;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PARENT);

            int j = results.length();


            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {


                JSONObject jo = results.getJSONObject(i);


                String title = jo.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String info = jo.getString(TAG_INFO);


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_INFO, info);


                bookList.add(map);
                if(mCallback!=null)
                {
                    mCallback.returnList(booklist);
                }


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements returnListListener
    {
    ListView list;
    URl url; /// initialize your url
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_form);
    new SnagData(MainActivity.this).execute(url); // url passed to doInbackgrounf
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.game_list);
    }
     public void returnList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list)
       {
      // set adapter with list here
      ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            list, R.layout.list_view, new String[] {
                    TAG_TITLE, TAG_INFO }, new int[] {
                    R.id.title, R.id.info });
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

     }
   }
```

Edit 2:

To the link in the comment (https://github.com/woolardjason/JavaTest)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements returnListListener {
    // Local Variables
    Context context;
    String mTAG = "NETWORK ACTIVITY - MainActivity Class";
    String mUrlString = "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/games/?api_key=84bb1f7ad08b299e6c29992eff7ed6278f406a15&format=json&limit=5&sort=original_release_date:asc&filter=expected_release_year:";
    String[] mReleaseYears;
    public static TextView resultsView;
    ListView mList;
    TextView name;
    TextView deck;
    TextView release;
    Boolean mConnected = false;


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gameList;
    // Node names from JSON Data
    String TAG_PARENT = "results";
    String TAG_NAME = "name";
    String TAG_DECK = "deck";
    String TAG_RELEASE = "expected_release_year";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_form);

        // Setting context local var to this activity.
        context = this;
        resultsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.results_view);
        // Setting mReleaseYears Local Var to String Array from resources
        mReleaseYears = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yearArray);
        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.game_list);
        // Creating Spinner Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mReleaseYears);
        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Creating the spinner
        Spinner viewSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.release_years);
        // Setting the spinners adapter to created adapter 'spinnerAdapter'
        viewSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        // Setting
        viewSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Setting Local Var Boolean 'mConnected' to the current
                // context's status
                mConnected = NetworkConn.grabConnectionStatus(context);
                // If connected...
                if (mConnected) {
                    // Performing a search using performSearch method based off
                    // current selected spinner position. Passes is data from
                    // array (mReleaseYears) based on selection to allow user
                    // manipulation of data.
                    //Data.performSearch(mUrlString + mReleaseYears[position]);
                    new Data(MainActivity.this).execute(mUrlString+ mReleaseYears[position]);
                    // If not connected...
                } else {
                    // Setting the result's view text
                    resultsView.setText(R.string.networkError);
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    adb.setMessage(R.string.networkError);
                    adb.setCancelable(true);
                    adb.setPositiveButton("Okay", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog errorAlert = adb.create();
                    errorAlert.show();
                }
            }

            // Method onNothingSelected...self explanatory method not utilized
            // at the moment.
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        // Setting list's item click listener

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void returnList(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // set adapter with list here
          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                list, R.layout.list_view, new String[] {
                        TAG_NAME, TAG_RELEASE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.release });
         mList.setAdapter(adapter);
         mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                // Method to be called upon item click within list
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // Setting the resultsView background color to dark
                    // gray (in case an error occurs, and it's currently
                    // red)
                    resultsView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    // Setting the resultView to display the current
                    // position's (in list) item details based off
                    // pulled in json data thats stored in gameList
                    resultsView.setText("Game: "
                            + list.get(+position).get(TAG_NAME)
                            + "\n"
                            + "About Game: "
                            + list.get(+position).get(TAG_DECK)
                            + "\n"
                            + "Release Year: "
                            + list.get(+position).get(TAG_RELEASE));
                }
            });
    }

}
```

Data

```
public class Data extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // Node names from JSON Data
    String TAG_PARENT = "results";
    String TAG_NAME = "name";
    String TAG_DECK = "deck";
    String TAG_RELEASE = "expected_release_year";
    static Context context;

    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public interface returnListListener
    {
          public void returnList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list);
    } 
    returnListListener mCallBack;
    public Data(Context context)
    {
       mCallBack = (returnListListener)context;
    }


    // onPreExecute Method - Setting TextView Cars to TextView IDS located
    // in xml
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Clearing out the GameList (for reloads)
        gameList.clear();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Resetting URL
        String fURL = "";
    //for (URL url : urls) {
            // Setting fURL stringVar to response of getURLReponse method
            // from WebClass class.
            fURL = NetworkConn.getURLResponse(urls[0]);
        //}
        // Returning fURL string var
        return fURL;
    }

    // OnPostExecute method
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            // Setting json var for type JSONObject to new JSOBObject with
            // passed in string result
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            // Setting results JSONArray var to results json node
            JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PARENT);
            // Setting j int var to results array length
            int j = results.length();
            // For conditional cycling through results array grabbing
            // defined nodes and storing them
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                // Setting JSONObject var 'jo' to each object within results
                // array
                JSONObject jo = results.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing pulled in JSON Nodes into separate strings
                String nam = jo.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String dec = jo.getString(TAG_DECK);
                String rel = jo.getString(TAG_RELEASE);

                // Creating HashMap entitled map and initializing it
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Putting JSON nodes into map
                map.put(TAG_RELEASE, rel);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, nam);
                map.put(TAG_DECK, dec);

                // Adding data to gameList Local var
                gameList.add(map);

                if(mCallBack!=null)
                {
                       mCallBack.returnList(gameList);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

NetworkConn

```
public class NetworkConn {
    static Boolean isConnected = false;
    static String mTAG = "NETWORK ACTIVITY - Webclass Class";
    public static Boolean grabConnectionStatus(Context context){
        checkConnectionStatus(context);
        return isConnected;
    }
    // checkConnectionStatus method
    public static void checkConnectionStatus(Context context) {
        // Obtaining context system service /Connectivity_Service
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // Obtaining active network info for created connectivitymanager instance
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        // checking if networkInfo is null or not
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            // checking if network info is connected
            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                // logging connection type if connected, and networkInfo is not null
                Log.i(mTAG, "connection type: " + networkInfo.getTypeName());
                // setting isConnected to true if connected and networkInfo is not null
                isConnected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    // getURLResponse method
    public static String getURLResponse(String url) {
        // Resetting response var by setting it to equal nothing.
        String response = "";
        try {
            // Initializing URLConnection
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = url1.openConnection();
            // Setting created bufferedinputstring to connection input stream
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
                    connection.getInputStream());
            // Setting contextByte
            byte[] contextByte = new byte[1024];
            // Setting int bytesRead
            int bytesRead = 0;
            // Setting StringBuffer entitled responseBuffer to new StringBuffer
            StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            // While conditional to check while bytesRead is
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(contextByte)) != -1) {
                response = new String(contextByte, 0, bytesRead);
                responseBuffer.append(response);
            }
            response = responseBuffer.toString();
            Log.i(mTAG, response);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            response = "Something happened, no info returned!";
            Log.e(mTAG, "Something happened, no info returned!", e);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: Okay so my new update to my Json class can be found here:http://pastebin.com/d1uVqzBs It's highlighting (MainActivity)context; in red and says ' MainActivity cannot be resolved to a type' did I need to add in new Json(MainActivity.this).execute(params); somewhere to fix this?

Comment: @user3117785 did you see the edit  `mCallback = (returnListListener)context;` pls see the edit full

Comment: Okay great, that error went away. Json json = new Json(); is now highlighted saying the constructor is not defined. Possibly I changed that incorrectly when removing "combining the classes" to remove the un-necessary one?

Comment: @user3117785 there is no need for Json class remove the code. Pls understand my previous comment and do check the final edit. It will work all you need to do is pass the url here  `new SnagData(MainActivity.this).execute(url);` rest all copy paste from my post

Comment: Got everything implemented, no crashes but for some odd reason my ListView still isn't showing up. Oh well... =/ thanks a lot anyways...I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: @user3117785 post your updated code by editing your post. Full code. list is populated by data??

Comment: Weird kept getting an eror when trying to edit. Here is my absolute full code, no crashes - but my data isn't properly being displayed in the listview. https://github.com/woolardjason/JavaTest

Comment: @user3117785 Wierd enough you do not use `new Data(MainActivity.this).execute(URL);` in Activity

Comment: @user3117785 pls check the edited post and if it helps mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick next to the answer once

Comment: Ah, don't know how I missed that...I think what it was is that when I originally tried that it was telling me 'execute' didn't exist in Data class. It turns out I was implementing it , in the wrong spot. Sorry new here, didn't know I had to accept it as answer or I would of a while ago... you my friend are a GENIUS.

Comment: I really think I need to learn a lot more before proceeding with this project, do you have any good tips as far as Android books to study?

Comment: Great thank you sir, I tried upvoting you but couldn't due to me not being reputable enough here yet - wish there was more I could do for all your hard work and help.